# Whats the right way to get the current user logging in using angular and django-rest-framework?

Tags: django, angular, django-rest-framework

Im using Angular as frontend and Django as backend. When fetching the logged in user, there is a small lag or "flickering" in the username displayed in the top menu due to the Angular having to ask the backend for the user data, after receiving the token and wait for the promise to return the user data.

To authenticate and log in i use django rest framework:

```
url(r'^token-auth/', obtain_auth_token)
```

This returns a Token - all works well and Im logged in. But this call doesnt return any user data, so to solve this I created a separate api view that returns the user. A service in Angular is triggered to fetch the user data directly after receiving the token.

But to do that Angular has to call the user view separately and that in turn can lead to "lag" in the way that the users data wont load instantly in the menu upon login (because Angular has to fetch the users data again, after receiving the users token on the first call).

This got me thinking, what is the best way to get the logged in user data after receiving the Token and "beeing logged in"? Is there a better way to do this?

Or if this is the correct way to do it maybe I should just handle the loading of data in the menu in a different way?

Comment: Why not you extend the `obtain_auth_token` which will provide the user details on a successful login?

Comment: Thats great! After searching I found CustomAuthToken in Django REST framework documentation. Thank you!